# Where can I find an ZK Teco SDK for Android?

Tags: android, sdk

I 'm developing an app for Android which makes use of fingerprint readers of ZK Teco. (LIVE20R)
I already purchased the device but I can't find an SDK for Android anywhere.
It is written on the package that they provide SDK for Windows, Linux and Android free.

So I ask for help here. If anyone has past experience in ZK machines for Android or anyone can find an SDK on the internet, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Please see if its there here https://www.zkteco.com/support/SDK/39_55.html

Comment: I tried there. But there are only SDKs for Windows.

Comment: Someone told me to try http://biometrics.zkteco.com/member.php. But I should log in to download. I applied several times but didn't get any answers yet. I'm very surprised that they are so unkind. I sent several tickets and emails to them but no answer. Is there anyone who has account there? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that ZK teco distributes SDK for Android to buyers.
After trying contacting them for a long time, I could finally get SDK.
:/

Comment: can you please give me the android sdk? I also have to integrate slk20r with android :( It will highly appreciable.

Comment: And kindly tell me one thing are you connecting slk20r with android using OTG?

Comment: Hi, guys. Sorry for late reply. I don't know if I may share it or not. I received it directly from them.